# Macro to move down and separate data

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-macro

I wish to use a macro in Google Sheets to

1. find the number 1 in column A
2. then move that corresponding row and all following rows down to start at A9 row
3. then find the number 2 in column A
4. then move that corresponding row and all following rows down to start at A25
5. then find the number 3 in column A
6. then move that corresponding row and all following rows down to start at A41 and so on down to number 24.

Each number 1,2,3,... has a varying number of data rows below it before the next number and so I can't simply do one "paste" at A9 with all of the information being in the correct place.

I have tried recording a macro using FIND menu item but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets the `Find` command highlights the cells that match the searched value. To jump (activate) a matching cell, instead use `Find and Replace`. Bear in mind that the macro recorder will not record any action for `Find` and for `Find and Replace` will only record the cell activation.

I suggest you that instead of the Google Sheets macro recorder write your script directly on the script editor. Once you did this, you could "Import" the script as a macro to be called from the Macros menu and / or  a custom keyboard shortcut.